# Prove that $a\alpha + b\beta ≥ a^\alpha + b^\beta$ given where a,b real(+) and $\alpha$,$\beta$ are rational(+) and $\alpha\beta = 1$.

Tags: inequality

> Given that $a$ and $b$ are positive real numbers, $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are positive rational numbers and $\alpha +\beta = 1$, prove that $$a\alpha + b\beta ≥ a^{\alpha}b^{\beta}$$

This appeared under the AM-GM inequality, however I'm having trouble correlating the inequality with the above problem.

Comment: This is still not quite right. Try $a=b=1, \alpha=\beta=1/2$.

Comment: I think the correct inequality is $$a\alpha+b\beta\ge a^\alpha b^\beta.$$

Comment: @QingZhang, you're right. I made a typo.

Comment: You need to change the title too.

Comment: If you know some calculus, you can try mean value theorem to the function ln(x).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\alpha = \frac{p}{q}$ then $\beta = \frac{q-p}{q}$ for some integer 
$p\leq q$. Write
\begin{equation*}
a\alpha+b\beta = \frac{1}{q}\left(\underbrace{a+\ldots+a}_{p \, \textrm{times}} + \underbrace{b+\ldots+b}_{q-p \, \textrm{times}}\right)
\geq \sqrt[q]{a^pb^{q-p}} = a^{\alpha}b^{\beta}.
\end{equation*}